# JBoss: BAS018759: Failed to load module

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss6.x

I'm getting following error when trying to deploy the WAR in jboss 6.2 EAP.

```
20:29:01,602 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-16) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.MyWar.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.MyWar.war".main: JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.MyWar.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.my.mywar:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1030) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1386) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1414) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:242) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 5 more
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment name="MyWar.war">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
        <module name="com.my.mywar">
            <imports>
                <include path="META-INF**"/>
                <include path="org**"/>
            </imports>
        </module>
    </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I'm not understanding which is the exact jar which is missing in module. If anyone can help me to identify will be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a jboss-deployments-structure in WEB-INF, and if so, whats the content?

Comment: Yes Martin. I have jboss-deployments-structure.xml and updated the content of it above.

Comment: remove the com.my.mywar  tag

Comment: I had already tried that but creating more issues after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got fixed when I created folder structure like "com/my/mywar" under jBossHome/modules and put the module.xml inside.